# Break down a complex string into a dictionary in python3

Tags: python

I have a string that look like this:

```
'[0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256], [200, 78, 570, 259, 85, 12, 8, 1, 0, 0]'
```

Basically the first list is the key, the second is the actual value, so I am trying to break down this string to get the appropriate key and value

How do I achieve as output something like this?

```
{0:200, 1:78, 2:570, 4:259, 8:85, 16:12, 32:8, 64:1, 128:0, 256:0}
```

I tried to split the string using `],` to break the 2 lists but that didn't work because the split removed the square bracket at the end of the first list

Comment: Use Counter method from Collection module

Answer (score 4):

If your string is safe and this format (so list, comma, list), you can use `ast.literal_eval` to get a tuple of two lists.

Then, with `zip`, you can merge elements in order from two iterables.

```py
import ast

s = '[0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256], [200, 78, 570, 259, 85, 12, 8, 1, 0, 0]'
x, y = ast.literal_eval(s)
d = dict(zip(x, y))
d
# {0: 200, 1: 78, 2: 570, 4: 259, 8: 85, 16: 12, 32: 8, 64: 1, 128: 0, 256: 0}
```